# What voltage should I use to heat a 36 gauge nichrome wire to 100 degrees Fahrenheit?

Tags: wire

I am making a foldable brass hanger, with a brass tube I will solder to the base. I am going to be using Nichrome 80-250 36 gauge wire, but I am not sure how many volts I need to get it up to 100 degrees Fahrenheit. If anyone could help me calculate this, I would be super thankful.

Comment: The hard part of a question like this is a thermodynamics problem, not an electrical problem. You need to specify the heat loss to the surrounding environment, and the mass and specific heat of all of the things you want to heat up. You also need to describe how **quickly** you want to reach temperature.

Comment: You also need to describe the environment. For example, if it's 100°F in the room, you don't need any power. But even if you supply all that I doubt anyone here is going to be able to give you a definitive answer. You might be better to pick a voltage that will cause a few watts to be dissipated and measure it, then adjust. For example if you have 3' that might be about 75 ohms so try 10-15V.

Comment: Better question will be: what the maximum Curren that size of wire can carry?

Comment: are you talking about 100 km of nichrome wire, outside, in antarctica, in winter?

Answer (score 1):

It depends entirely on how much heat is removed by the surroundings. In a vacuum, with a small voltage across it, it will continue to rise in temperature until it nearly melts. At which point the light radiation given off starts to be a source of energy removal and the "filament" kind of temperature stabilizes.

In other words, by removing heat (air, flow of air etc.) it keeps the the object being heated to a finite and controllable value but, only if you understand the thermal equations for the heat being removed and, for a complex shaped material that isn't an easy thing to speculate on.

However, if you know the resistance of the wire at the temperature you want, a control system can be made to keep the wire at the right temperature within certain limits of air-movement.

Or, use a separate temperature sensor to control temperature.